# Magento 1.9: Cart dropping products when user click on "Add to Cart"

Tags: magento, cart

I started having a weird issue from a couple of days. I notice in my Google Analytics visitors were keep dropping from **cart page** so I added a session recording app and saw some visitors when clicking on **add to cart button** it redirects them to empty cart page but some users don't have this issues and have their transaction goes through smoothly.

What can be the actual reason? I tried on my computer and it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a log in the cart adding class/function so you will be able to examine it later and see exactly what went wrong.